# Show depth on the page edge of the book (Turn.js)

Tags: javascript

> https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/260
>
> http://turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs

I tried to do the same by keeping the .own-size class on the covers, but the "display" gets set to "none" for the 'cover pages' on navigating through the book. Why is it happening like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding 'fixed' class to the cover pages solves the problem